# Read each line of file using MappedByteBuffer in java

Tags: java, performance, file, nio

I am working on a task where I have to read a huge file (~1.5 GB in size and approximately 16000000 records). I have 2 options in front of me:

1. use BufferReader where I can get the each row in string.
2. use MappedByteBuffer with FileChannel and RandomAccessFile.

In raw test, to read no. of records with option 1, it takes around 2900 ms and in option 2, it takes around 1450 ms.

The test programs are as follows:

Option 1:

```
public static void reviewBufferedReader () {
    long lineNumber = 0;
    String line = null;
    try (BufferedReader b = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("D:\\\\Temp Data Files\\Data1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        executor = RecordsDistributionExecutor.getInstance();
        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error in reviewBufferedReader : "+e.getMessage());
    } finally {

    }
    System.out.println("Total no. of lines: "+lineNumber);
}
```

Option 2:

```
public static void reviewFileChannelWithMappedByteBuffer () {
    long lineNumber = 0;
    try (RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\\\Temp Data Files\\Data2.txt", "r");
            FileChannel inChannel = raFile.getChannel();){
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, inChannel.size());
        buffer.load(); 
        char c;
        for(int i = 0; i< buffer.limit(); i++) {
            c = (char) buffer.get();
            if ('\n' == c) {
                lineNumber++;
            }
        }
        buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error in reviewFileChannelWithMappedByteBuffer : "+e.getMessage());
    } finally {

    }
    System.out.println("Total no. of lines: "+lineNumber);
}
```

As I said, Option 2 takes less time with basic testing.

I have a question, is it possible to read the file data line by line in option 2 like option 1.

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: Why do you want to read line-by-line in your second example if your goal is to just count the number of lines? Also, have you tried `Files.lines(path).count()`?

Comment: Hi @JacobG. It is just a test code. Actually I want to read the line one by one from the file.

Comment: Eugen has the answer you seek: https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: Hey @fram, those option I already gone through and those options are always available. I am just trying to do it with available resources only, not trying to add additional dependencies.

Comment: Use `BufferedReader`. It's fast enough, it already works, and it handles line terminators better than your present option 2 code. What you do with each line will swamp the I/O time completely.

Comment: Yes it is faster but just want to try with MappedByteBuffer. If I am able to read the line efficiently with MappedByteBuffer, how much difference it will create and what that I want to analyse.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you:  the difference will be basically zero when you add in your processing of each line. Don't optimise steps that are not rate-determining. Get on with your real work.

Comment: Ohh ..ok. Got your point @user207421 . Thanks :)